# Wrestling HaSatan

Tags: sources-mekorot, commentaries, vayishlach

I know there are many explanations on who Ya’akov wrestled with. But I came across an explanation teaching it was HaSatan he wrestled with. Hoped someone could give me the sources or explanations which teach this.

Answer (score 6):

[Kli Yakar Bereishit 32:25](https://www.sefaria.org/Kli_Yakar_on_Genesis.32.25.1?lang=bi):

> אחר שהסכימו רוב המפרשים שמלאך זה הוא סמא״ל שרו של עשו הנקרא סמא״ל עשו, כי כל חפצו וישעו לסמא עיני האדם ולהכותו בעורון ולעשותו סומא מעין השכלי, עד אשר לא יוכל הרואה לראות במראות האמת לבא ולראות פני ה' ולבוא בסוד ה' ליראיו בסתרי התורה, **כי הוא שטן**, הוא מלאך המות, הוא יצה״ר
>
> Most of the commentators agree that this angel is Samael, the ministering angel of Esav, who is called "Samael Esav", because his entire desire is to blind a person's eyes and to strike him with blindness and to make his mind's eye 'blind', to the extent that that he is unable to see with the truth, to come and 'see' the face of Hashem and to enter in to the mysteries of the secrets of the Torah that Hashem grants to those that fear him, **for he is Satan**, he is the Angel of Death, he is the Evil Inclination.

Comment: בבראשית רבה (פע"ז ב) ר' חמא בר חנינא אמר, שרו של עשו היה

Comment: @IsraelReader Can you clarify what point you're trying to make? The Midrash Rabbah doesn't seem to identify שרו של עשו with Satan.

Comment: The equation of Satan = Esav's ministering angel is clearly the Kli Yakar's unnamed "commentators". However I sought to provide a source from Chazal, that at least addresses the first assumption that Jacob's adversary was in fact Esav's ministering angel.

Comment: בפי' הרוקח עה"ת (פ' וישלח, עמ' רמט) לבד"ו ויאב"ק בגימטריא לסמא"ל

Comment: Contrast this with Yalkut Shimoni (Torah, 132) who quotes some as saying that Jacob's adversary was Michael (!)

Comment: Another opinion is that it was Gavriel [Rabbeinu Bachye (Breishis 32:30), Yalkut Reuveini in the name of the Zohar].